# How to install TCL packages: uuid,Itcl, html, tdom, tdom, tepam, math::bignum

Tags: tcl

I need help to install  the following TCL packages:

1. uuid
2. Itcl
3. html
4. tdom
5. tdom
6. tepam
7. math::bignum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`uuid`, `html`, `tepam`, and `math::bignum` all appear to be provided by package `tcllib`

```
/usr/share/tcltk/tcllib1.18/html/html.tcl
/usr/share/tcltk/tcllib1.18/math/bignum.tcl
/usr/share/tcltk/tcllib1.18/tepam/tepam.tcl
/usr/share/tcltk/tcllib1.18/tool/uuid.tcl
/usr/share/tcltk/tcllib1.18/uuid/uuid.tcl
```

specifically, in tcl8.6

```
% package require uuid
1.0.5
% package require html
1.4.4
% package require tepam
0.5
% package require math::bignum
3.1.1
%
```

`tdom` and `itcl` are provided by separate packages, namely

```
apt-cache show tdom
Description-en: fast XML/DOM/XPath/XSLT extension for Tcl written in C

apt-cache show itcl3
Description-en: [incr Tcl] OOP extension for Tcl - run-time files
```